# Get files for each language in model (MVC 3) using HttpContext to save them in separate table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have this simple piece of HTML code:

```
<div>
   <input type="file" name="english-file" />
</div>
<div>
   <input type="file" name="french-file" />
</div>
```

I used in my model, the following C# line code:

```
object receivedFiles = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["english-file"];
```

but that object returns null always.

Of course that I can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files` but I want to sepparate files by languages (the above HTML code is simple but someone could add more files to `english` than `french` with +Add files button) and save them in sepparate table.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how files are uploaded. You should look in `Request.Files["english-file"]` after setting the proper `enctype` on the form.

Let's take an example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("upload", "somecontroller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="english" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="french" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
}
```

and in the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    var englishFile = Request.Files["english"];
    var frenchFile = Request.Files["french"];
    ...
}
```

or even better:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase english, HttpPostedFileBase french)
{
    ...
}
```

or even better:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    ...
}
```

assuming you adjust the names of the file inputs:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("upload", "somecontroller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="files" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="files" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
}
```

I also invite you to read the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx).

Comment: What's happens if I want to upload 3 files for english (in this case 3 input type='file' name = 'english-file'  and 2 for french ) ?

Comment: , you will have 3 file inputs, or if you are using a modern browser you could set the `multiple="multiple"` attribute on the french file input which allows you to select multiple files in the dialog.

Comment: I'm refered to model logic. How to see files for english because with `var englishFile = Request.Files["english"];` you will see the first file, not all.

Comment: @MichaelSwan, you could use `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files`  as action argument which will give you a list of files as shown in my last example.

Comment: and same thing for french file(s) ?

Comment: like `public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> english, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> french)` ?

Comment: Yes, this could work assuming your file inputs are named accordingly.

Comment: In the last case, how can i discern between english and french?